# Equivalent of PHP's stripslashes() in C?

Tags: php, c, stripslashes

was wondering if an Equivalent of PHP's `stripslashes()` in C existed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because this is not a problem that is usually encountered in C. If you want the same functionality then you will need to write it yourself, or find some library that provides it.